# Asp.NET 5 listen to tcp socket

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets, tcp, asp.net-core

System.Net.Sockets seems to only be available in Asp.Net 4.5/4.6.

Is there a way to do this in Asp.Net 5 or are there plans to?

Comment: Well have you included a dependency for the `System.Net.Sockets` package?

Comment: I would, if it supported .NET 5. Hence my question :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. There's a Nuget package that you should include in your project.json file. Have you tried that? Please post your project.json file and what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32302367/1977808, you must also include "System.Private.Networking" in your package.json file in order to use "System.Net.Sockets", although I am unsure of why this is.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a dependency on the `System.Net.Sockets` nuget package. Here's a complete example:

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Listen().Wait();
    }

    static async Task Listen()
    {
        var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 10000);
        listener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection");
        var socket = await listener.AcceptSocketAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Client connected!");
    }
}
```

Project file:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "TestVSCode Console Application",
  "dependencies": {
    "System.Net.Sockets": "4.1.0-beta-23516",
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the question was about in ASP.NET!

Comment: @TejasviHegde: When this was asked, "ASP.NET 5" was the name for what became ASP.NET Core 1.0. So this answer is basically showing how to make `TcpListener` available in .NET Core. The fact that I happened to use it in a console application is irrelevant.